# String equality in asm bytecode

Tags: java, assembly, compiler-construction, jvm, bytecode

I am trying to do this in bytecode:

```
if("asd"=="asd"){}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: Main, method: main signature: ([LJava/lang/String:)V) Expecting to find integer on stack
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclareMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

IF_ICMPEQ is integer comparison (This is what ICMP means)  You want to compare references with IF_ACMPEQ

BTW you don't need to store and then load the values, you can just use the values on the stack.

Comment: I suggest you look at the ASM bytecode plugin.  You can write Java code and it will show you the byte code and ASM code to produce it in another window.

Comment: Also, Tony, you have posted several questions in the past week, and you have not accepted answers for any of them.  This is considered poor StackOverflow etiquette; if someone takes the time to answer your question, and you are satisfied with the answer, you should upvote it and mark it as accepted.  We get reputation points when you do this.